# How to accept RPC ping with PHP

Tags: php, xml, rpc, ping

I'm trying to make pinging service that will accept pings like other big aggregators.
I'm using phpxmlrpc from http://phpxmlrpc.sourceforge.net/

My sample code is trying just to accept ping and to save all data in log:

```
function add ($xmlrpcmsg) 
{
    $a = php_xmlrpc_decode($xmlrpcmsg->getParam(0));
    $b = php_xmlrpc_decode($xmlrpcmsg->getParam(1));
    $c = php_xmlrpc_decode($xmlrpcmsg->getParam(2));
    $d = php_xmlrpc_decode($xmlrpcmsg->getParam(3));




    $current= file_get_contents('test_log.txt');
    $ww=$a.$b.$c.$d.'
    '.$current;
    file_put_contents('test_log.txt', $ww);



    return true; // returning response
}


$s = new xmlrpc_server(
            array(
                "example.add" =>  array( // xml-rpc function/method name
                    "function" => "add", // php function name to use when "example.add" is called
                    "signature" => array(array($xmlrpcString, $xmlrpcString, $xmlrpcString, $xmlrpcString)), // signature with defined IN and OUT parameter types
                    "docstring" =>  'Testing' // description of method
                    )          
            )
        );
```

But it doesn't work.
If I ping with wordpress or any other pinger nothing happen in log.

Does anybody have idea what is wrong with my code, or if you can suggest any other easier method to accept RPC XML ping and get data from it.

Comment: Tip: you don't need to load your log file. just use `file_put_contents(filename, data, FILE_APPEND)`.

Answer (score 1):

Or maybe I should first see what data is RPC ping sending?
Do you know how can I set some listener that will save all POST and head data to txt file and then analyze it.
I mean to send regular ping from wordpress and to see format of that data.

Comment: Ok, I got this part - $data = file_get_contents('php://input');

Comment: please, tell me some details!